# Migrating from frontend to backend web development

Tags: web-applications, web-deployment, backend, web-architecture

I mostly do front end web development but I want to shift to backend web development.

I have some experience with backend development. I developed a basic website using Ruby-on-Rails but I didn't 'get' a lot of stuff; I just did it because some tutorial or screencast said so. Basically I somehow hacked it together. So, I understand MVC pattern and have some idea about backend development.

However, I want to learn backend developmet, so that I can develop a production quality dynamic database-driven web applications. What should be the roadmap?(I am on a 6 month break from work.) Again, I just really want to 'get' it.

At present when I read stuff on web, I find myself lost with a lot of terms. I want to understand the architecture. For example I read some posts on highscalability.com about the architecture if different websites and felt completely lost. So, I want to understand all that stuff.

Also, I would want to learn how to develop a JSON api which can be used for iOS apps and stuff.

I would want to know how to use something like AWS or heroku to deploy apps.

Also, I wouldn't want to start with a high level framework like RoR because they hide away a lot of stuff. Rather I would want to start with node.js since I already have experience with JS, also I think it would help me learn the internals better.

Edit : Yes, I read the SO answer on nodejs resources but that just helps me learn nodejs API. Not the other stuff I have mentioned above.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  You question is a better fit for the sister site: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/  as SO is for more specific questions.  Just my 2-cents as someone who does a lot of backend work (accounting related): Books/Internet are good to get some basic knowledge, but you need real projects to hit the snags that will educate you in a well rounded way.   Start by making some projects for yourself.  When you feel comfortable, take on a small no-pressure client.  Experience stuff !!

Comment: @markE Thanks for your response! Also, is there some way to migrate the question from one site to other?

Comment: Copy - Paste - Delete original question ...